# Lemma for proving Zermelo's theorem

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I'm trying to understand the following lemma in Bourbaki's set theory (chapter III, §2,no. 3,Lemma 3):

Lemma 3: Let $E$ be a set, let $S$ be a subset of $P(E)$, and let $p$ be a mapping of $S$ into $E$ such that $p(X)\notin X$ for all $X\in S$. Then there exists a subset $M$ of $E$ and a well-ordering $\Gamma$ on $M$ such that, if $x\leq y$ denotes $y\in \Gamma(x)$ and $S_x$ denotes the segment $]\leftarrow,x[$,

1. for all $x\in M$ we have $S_x\in S$ and $p(S_x)=x$;
2. $M\notin S$

(note that "segment" means "initial segment")
The following figure, shows a very simplistic scenario:

[image]

The conditions of the lemma are satisfied in the mapping shown ($p(X)\notin X$ for all $X\in S$), however, any ordered $M\subset E$ that you take, will have segments that are not in $S$ (e.g. $\emptyset$). So what's the conclusion 1 of the lemma all about?

Comment: Why are you reading Bourbaki's set theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am aware of the criticisms that Bourbaki's set theory receives, however among the books I could read (e.g. Kunen's) I liked the style of this one the most. Before talking about sets, it develops the formal language first. It clearly states that a set is nothing more than a term in the formal language and I really like that. Also, with Bourbaki's books, you never run into some terminology that's not defined before. It's always very clear.   
These aside, the truth of this lemma should not depend on the author of the book :)

Comment: It's not about the truth of the lemma. It's that reading Bourbaki does not lead to knowing any set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\emptyset\notin S$ (as in your example), one can choose $M=\emptyset$ and condition 1 becomes trivial. Otherwise, $M$ cannot be empty, it has a least element $a$, which is $p(\emptyset)$ by condition 1. If  $A= \{a\}$ is not in $S$, one can choose $M=A$, otherwise $M$ has a second element, which is $p(A)$, etc. More generally, if $x\in M$, and $B$ is the set of elements $\le x$, either $B\in S$, case where $p(B)$ is the successor of $x$ or $B\notin S$, case where $M=B$.

The proof of the lemma is a clever use of the uniqueness property given by condition 1.